# Clear everything after prompt in fish shell?

Tags: fish

I want to make keybinding that simply clears everything I entered after prompt and till the end. The same behavior as what `Ctr+c` does, but without appending `^C` character to the end of current line and newline. Is it doable somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function clear_to_end
  commandline (commandline --cut-at-cursor)
end
bind \cc clear_to_end
```

This sets the command line to the current command line, truncated at the cursor.

Comment: Can you please add how to go to beginning of line (right after the prompt), I found in default keybindings that its `beginning-of-line`, but I cant understand how to invoke it from function.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to set the command line to be truncated at the cursor, and then jump to the beginning of the line?

Comment: I want to truncate everything from prompt, basically clearing all input made

Comment: Now I understand. See [my comment on issue 3535](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3535#issuecomment-259538701) for one way to do this.

Answer (score 33):

You probably want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> and/or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>

Ctrl-u kills characters from your cursor to the start of entry (the prompt)
Ctrl-k kills characters from your cursor to the end of the line.

The deleted characters can be pasted (yanked) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>